# How can I add version comments as a column in my slide library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, document-library

There is a "comment" field in the version history where users can add a comment why they updated the slide. Is there a way to show these comments in a column directly in the slide library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your view to include the "Check In Comment" (usually listed within the first 10 options), this will create a column in your Document Library that shows the comment inputted when checking in a file, or slide in this case.